# Emergency stop: job aborted, no legal \end found

Tags: errors, compilation-error, missing

[image]

```
Emergency stop.

<*> Main_file.tex
                 
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13088 strings out of 492164
 254952 string characters out of 6125314
 329325 words of memory out of 5000000
 17107 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 12006 words of font info for 44 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 60i,12n,54p,634b,492s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Without more information it is impossible to tell you. Can you for example show us a short tex code resulting in your issue?

Comment: The error you show is the last one, and in TeX usually only the first error matters. Show the first error, please, and a compilable example that shows the issue.

Comment: I am totally new to latex. The first error it shows is at line 31 "You have used a \\ or \newline command where LaTeX was not expecting one."  although there is no newline on 31. And what do you mean by compilable example?

Comment: Line 31 is `\tableofcontents`, so probably somewhere in the table of contents there is an unexpected newline. However, without a compilable example it is hard to tell for sure. Such an example is the smallest possible, but still complete code that shows the issue. The goal is to provide code (as text, not in an image) that can be copy-pasted as a new document and when compiled it shows the error that you ask about.

Comment: One way to make such an example document is to remove as much content, packages, headers, etc. as you can, while the error remains. Especially try to remove all `\input` statements because they refer to files that we don't have. If the error disappears after removing an `\input` statement then the problem is in that file, in that case you should copy the relevant content of the other file into your minimal example code so that you can still show the error within the self-contained example.

Comment: Check all of your ``\\`` tokens. There should never be one in normal text; if you want to force a line break in a section title you should also supply the optional argument to `\section` (or similar command) without the forced line break: ``\section[A long title]{A long \\ title}``.

Comment: is there some way to send someone a link on this platform who can edit it?

Comment: The idea is that you try yourself to make the problem as clear and isolated as possible, so that people here on the site can concentrate on the actual issue instead of looking through long and irrelevant parts of the code. This is not only in the interest of people that provide answers, but also to make the question more useful to future visitors which may have the same problem and can apply the solution to their own situation, but only if the problem is sufficiently isolated.

Comment: And often when you are in the process of creating a minimal compilable example then you find the source of the problem yourself and you are able to solve it without any further assistance, which is a good way of learning LaTeX.

Comment: I have almost figured it out if I shift the end document statement above the error vanishes I guess it's happening because of many rows between begin{document} and end{document}. what is the limit?

Comment: There are limits to the number of lines/bytes but they are quite high, LaTeX documents can be thousands of pages long. You can also see from the memory summary at the end that you are well within the limits. The more likely explanation is that in some line near the end of the document there is an error, and when shifting `\end{document}` up the error is not encountered anymore (LaTeX immediately stops processing when `\end{document}` is seen).